# Error in Timestamp conversion in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake. I am using a control table in my ETL process. I want to update current timestamp in watermark_value field of my control table. Below is my procedure code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp()
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$  
  
    var result = "";  
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"} );  
    

    try {   
  
        var max_sync_sql_command = `SELECT watermark_value,dateadd(minute, -1, sysdate()) as new_watermark_value  
                                        from APPLICATION_CONTROL 
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'; `
        
        var max_sync_time_result = snowflake.execute ({ sqlText: max_sync_sql_command });
        
        max_sync_time_result.next();            
        var max_sync_time = max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(1);  
        var new_watermark_value = (max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(2));  
 
        /*Some ETL Code Here*/ 

        var update_watermark_sql_command = `update APPLICATION_CONTROL  
                                            set watermark_value =  to_varchar(  to_timestamp( '`+new_watermark_value+`', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                                            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'; `

        snowflake.execute ({ sqlText: update_watermark_sql_command });
        
        snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "COMMIT;"} );
        result = "Record updated Successfully"
        }
        catch (err)  
        {
        snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "ROLLBACK;"} );
        result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
        result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
        }
  
    return result;    
  
  $$;
```

I am getting below error during procedure execution

```
Failed: Code: 100183
  State: P0000
  Message: Can't parse 'Fri Jun 11 2021 12:47:38 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)' as timestamp with format 'DY MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZD'
Stack Trace:
At Snowflake.execute, line 25 position 12
```

datatype of watermark_value column in application_control table is TIMESTAMP_NTZ.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have converted timestamp into character(Used to_char function) while fetching values and it worked.

```
var max_sync_sql_command = `SELECT watermark_value,to_char(dateadd(minute, -1, sysdate())) as new_watermark_value  
                                        from APPLICATION_CONTROL 
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'; `
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns are in the wrong order when you are getting results from the query

```
var max_sync_time = max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(1);  
var new_watermark_value = (max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(2));
```

should be

```
var max_sync_time = max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(2);  
var new_watermark_value = (max_sync_time_result.getColumnValue(1));
```

**UPDATE**

Having done some of research, it seems like the way Snowflake handles dates/times, when transferring values from SQL to Javascript and back again, is a bit odd. There's mention of SFDATE types but this is not, in my opinion documented very well.

Anyway, the following code structure should work - though why it works and what you were trying doesn't is anybody's guess:

```
var update_watermark_sql_command = `update APPLICATION_CONTROL  
                                    set watermark_value =  :1 
                                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'; `

snowflake.execute ({ sqlText: update_watermark_sql_command, binds: [new_watermark_value.toISOString()] });
```

Comment: it didnt work,  my column order is right. I just want to convert Sat  Jun 12 2021 09:35:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) into time format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Comment: It looks like watermark_value is a varchar? Why are you storing a timestamp in a varchar - why not store it in a timestamp column and display it in whatever format you want in a query?

Comment: Then why are you converting the value you are writing to this column to varchar?

Comment: earlier, I tried without converting , but got the above mentioned error.